# Improving controller performance in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, redis

I am building an application with symfony2. I have more than 200000+ data in my database.for this I am using redis server to improve performance, which actually reduced my doctrine query time. but still my page load time is more than 9 second, i hosted all css, js locally to check the impact of the load time, then i figured out my controller is taking most of  the time: here is the code of the controller:

```
$episodesByContent = array();
    foreach ($episodes as $episode) {
        if (!array_key_exists($episode['content_id'], $episodesByContent)) {
            $episodesByContent[$episode['content_id']] = array();
        }
        $episodesByContent[$episode['content_id']][] = $episode;
    }

    $data = array();

    foreach ($contents as &$content) {

        $content['select']  = '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $content['id'] . '" id="'. $content['id'] . '"  name="multiselect_checkbox" class="multiselect_checkbox">';
        $content['actions'] = '';
        if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted(array('ROLE_CONTENT_NEW_RO','ROLE_CONTENT_NEW_RW',' ROLE_CONTENT_GENERAL_RW'))) {
            $link = $this->generateUrl('content_show', array(
                'id' => $content['id'],
            ));
            $content['actions'] .= '<a href="' . $link . '" rel="tooltip" title="Show" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-icon icon-left" role="button">
                <i class="entypo-info"></i> Show
            </a>';
        }
        if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_CONTENT_NEW_RW')) {
            $link = $this->generateUrl('content_edit', array(
                'id' => $content['id'],
            ));
            $content['actions'] .= '<a href="' . $link . '" rel="tooltip" title="Edit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-icon icon-left" role="button" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')">
                <i class="entypo-pencil"></i> Edit
            </a>';
        }
        $data[] = $content;


        if (array_key_exists($content['id'], $episodesByContent)) {
            foreach ($episodesByContent[$content['id']] as $episode) {
                $episode['select']            = '';
                $episode['priority']          = $content['priority'];
                $episode['owner']             = $content['owner'];
                $episode['sequence']          = $content['sequence'];
                $episode['category']          = $content['category'];
                $episode['category_sequence'] = $content['category_sequence'];
                $episode['actions']           = '';
                $data[] = $episode;
            }
        }
    }



    $encoders    = array(new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
    $serializer  = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    $datatable   = $this->get("bbd_datatables.content");
    $datatable->setData($serializer->serialize($data, "json"));
```

This part is taking 8 seconds.Can anyone suggest how can i reduce the load time for the controller?

and this is the query that im storing to redis cache:

```
public function getContentList(){

    $cacheDriver = new RedisCache();
    $cacheDriver->setRedis(new Client());

        if ($cacheDriver->contains('_content')){
        return $cacheDriver->fetch('_content');
        }

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.id, c.title, c.sequence, c.sequence_count, c.category_sequence, c.unique_id, c.priority, c.status, c.created_at,c.kaltura_id')
        ->addSelect('o.slug as owner')
        ->addSelect('cat.slug as category')
        ->addSelect("group_concat(m.name SEPARATOR ',') AS media")
        ->addSelect("group_concat(a.name SEPARATOR ',') AS album")
        ->innerJoin('c.content_owner', 'o')
        ->innerJoin('c.category', 'cat')
        ->leftJoin('c.media', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('c.albums', 'a')
        ->groupBy('c.id');

    $query= $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    $cacheDriver->save('_content', $query, 3600);

    return $query;


}
```

and in my profiler i see 15 queries and 1035ms. is that good enough?

Comment: write your query by hand

Comment: i dont have any other option but to create complex query

Answer (score 0):

As calls to `isGranted()` don't depends on the actual `$content`, move those calls out of any loop by saving it value in a variable.

You should also avoid using references in your `foreach ($contents as &$content)` loop.